# how to replace a text with quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to replace the `' ",'` to `'",'`. I need to remove all spaces but not the space in `Abc CDE`. In the end of each line there's also a space that I want to remove.

I was trying powershell but this doesn't work:

```
set "search=' ",'"
set "replace='",'"
:DoReplace
echo ^(Get-Content "aaa.TXT"^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "%search%", "%replace%" } ^| Set-Content "New.txt">Rep.ps1
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass -File Rep.ps1
```

This is the example I use:

```
"0","46","","","","Abc CDE ApS                   ","","","","","81602832            ","","","","","","","","","","" 
"0","46","","","","Abc CDE ApS                   ","","","","","81602832            ","","","","","","","","","","" 
"0","46","","","","John Stewart                  ","","","","","85505637            ","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell you could use a regular expression replacement like this:

```
(Get-Content 'aaa.txt') -replace ' +(",)','$1' | Set-Content 'aaa.txt'
```

but a much cleaner approach would be to import the file as a CSV and trim trailing spaces from each column, since the file seems to be a CSV anyway:

```
$csv = 'aaa.txt'
$outfile = 'bbb.txt'

# generate artificial headers
$cnt = @((Get-Content $csv -TotalCount 1) -split '","').Count
$headers = 1..$cnt | ForEach-Object { [string][char]($_+64) }

Import-Csv $csv -Header $headers | ForEach-Object {
  foreach ($prop in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
    $_.$($prop.Name) = $prop.Value.Trim()
  }
  $_
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File $outfile
```

With that said, for a batch approach (you should have mentioned that in your question) it would usually be much simpler to just use a Windows version of [`sed`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed -i "s/ \+\",/\",/g" aaa.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it that what you want?

```
$a = '"0","46","","","","Abc CDE ApS                   ","","","","","81602832            ","","","","","","","","","","" '

# delete all ' "'
While($a -like '* "*')
{
    $a = $a -replace ' "', '"'
}

# delete last character
$a = $a.subString(0,$a.length-1)

# whrite it into the console
echo ""
echo $a
```

Comment: Thanks @IkeRoyle It works but I need this in a batch file and I don't know how to do it. Can you please help me? I have a txt file with multiple lines and I want to copy to a new file without the spaces.

Comment: Well, can your read Batch-files? If yes, you could run the powershell-file with your batch -> take the info from your txt-file, edit it and whrite it into another txt-file -> then read this with a Batch-file // right now I don't have the time to bring you a new solution. If my awser above helped you, you could mark it as awnser. Good luck!